# Convert SQL to Laravel Eloquent Statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been working on a few tables where through a rather complex relationship (that I'm trying to clean up, but I still need reports made from the data through my Laravel).

At the moment, I can pull the data using the following SQL query to my MySQL database:

```
SELECT
customers.id,
customers.customer_name,
SUM(shipments.balance) AS shipmentBalance

FROM customers

LEFT JOIN shipments 
ON customers.id = shipments.bill_to  
AND balance > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0)                
    FROM payments_distributions               
    WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number)
GROUP BY customers.id, customers.customer_name
ORDER BY shipmentBalance DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I'm just not sure how to rewrite it properly into the whereRaw or DB::raw statements that Laravel Eloquent requires, as my previous attempts have failed.

### Update

Here is the closest solution I have tried:

```
DB::table('customers')
        ->select('customers', DB::raw('SUM(shipments.balance) AS shipmentBalance'))
        ->leftJoin(
                 DB::raw('
                        (select shipments 
                        ON customers.id = shipments.bill_to
                        AND balance > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0) 
                            FROM payments_distributions 
                            WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number)'))
        ->groupBy('customers.id')
        ->orderByRaw('shipmentBalance DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

### Update 2

Edit for Dom:

Using everything as it stands with your answer, I get the following response:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'on clause' (SQL: select customers.id, customers.customer_name,SUM(s.balance) AS shipmentBalance from `customers` left join `shipments` as `s` on `customers`.`id` = `s`.`bill_to` and s.balance > (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0) FROM payments_distributions WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = s.pro_number) = `` group by `customers`.`id`, `customers`.`customer_name` order by SUM(s.balance) DESC limit 5)
```

But if I remove this section, it brings up the page and the customers (though in the wrong order as I have removed one of the necessary components:

```
$join->on(DB::raw('s.balance > 
            (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0)                
            FROM payments_distributions               
            WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = s.pro_number)
                                            '));
```

Is there anything I can provide you with to get this specific statement to work with your entire answer?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've included what I thought was the closest to the best statement so far but still no luck.

Comment: Hi Matthew. While replying to people is not strictly obligatory here, this question appears to be in limbo, since there is one answer without any discussion, and one awaiting a reply from you. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```php
DB::table('customers')
    ->select('customers.id', 'customers.customer_name', DB::raw('SUM(shipments.balance) AS shipmentBalance'))
    ->leftJoin('shipments', function($join) {
        $join->on('customers.id', 'shipments.bill_to')
            ->where('balance', '>', function($query) {
                $query->selectRaw('IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0)')
                    ->from('payments_distributions')
                    ->where('payments_distributions.shipment_id', DB::raw('pro_number'));
            });
    })
    ->groupBy('customers.id', 'customers.customer_name')
    ->orderByDesc('shipmentBalance')
    ->limit(5)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the Models containing relationships or being able to test on this specific project, this is the most eloquent way I can think of performing your task.

The benefit of starting with the Customer model is you will have a [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) and can [paginate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) as needed.  Also review the [eloquent docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent), they help you understand all the different options.  Hope his helps.

P.S.  Start by using your model in your controller or wherever you are placing this query with:

```
use App\Customer
```

**The query**

```
$theQuery = Customer::select(DB::raw('customers.id, customers.customer_name,SUM(s.balance) AS shipmentBalance'))
        ->leftJoin('shipments as s', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('customers.id', '=', 's.bill_to');
            $join->on(DB::raw('s.balance > 
                                (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0)                
                                    FROM payments_distributions               
                                    WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = s.pro_number)
                            '));    
        })
        ->groupBy('customers.id', 'customers.customer_name')
        ->orderByRaw('SUM(s.balance) DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

Comment: I have made an edit to my question as I received an error which originates in the second of the inner joins. Could I provide you with any additional information that might help you with this new error? Thanks again - Matt

Comment: @Ma What does this retrieve when you query it?  And where is pro_number defined?  
(SELECT IFNULL(SUM(payments_distributions.amount),0)                
    FROM payments_distributions               
    WHERE payments_distributions.shipment_id = pro_number)

Comment: pro_number comes from the shipments table. Though if I put in what you sent as you sent it, I don't return anything, and that I think is because of the JOIN that's required between the shipments and the payments_distributions.

Comment: Got it, so I'm guessing that is a crossover join to the original query.  Let me update then try my update.

Comment: @Matthew Did you have a chance to try the Eloquent query I provided?  Let me know if that resolves it.